# Accessing Axios error from Laravel error validation

Tags: axios, vuejs3, laravel-api

I build Laravel-API which communicate with frontend via axios and VUE 3

This is my laravel TransactionController :

```
public function store(TransactionRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            $transaction = Transaction::create($request->all());

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Transaction created.',
                'data' => $transaction
            ], Response::HTTP_OK);
        } catch (QueryException $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => $e->errorInfo
            ], Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

    }
```

I'm using custom validation from FormRequest :

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'amount' => ['required', 'numeric'],
            'type' => ['required', 'in:expense,revenue']
        ];
    }

    protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
    {
        $response = new JsonResponse([
                    'message' => 'The given data is invalid', 
                    'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ], 422);

        throw new \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException($validator, $response);
    }
```

This is my Create.vue :

```
<script>
import { reactive, ref } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    setup() {
        const transaction = reactive({
            title: '',
            amount: '',
            time: '',
            type: ''
        });

        const validation = ref([]);

        const router = useRouter();

        function store() {
            axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/transaction', transaction)
            .then(() => {
                router.push({
                    name: 'transaction.index'
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                validation.value = err.response.data
                console.log(validation)
            });
        }

        return {
            transaction,
            validation,
            router,
            store
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried my API using post man and this is the result :

```
{
    "message": "The given data is invalid",
    "errors": {
        "title": [
            "The title field is required."
        ],
        "amount": [
            "The amount field is required."
        ],
        "type": [
            "The type field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Working as expected,

But when i tried to console log in browser, the result was complicated, like nested Object and array, please see the picture

How can I access the "data" property or how to keep it as simple as postman's result ?

[image: console.log() result]?

Answer (score 0):

In your function add .errors, this will return all errors that are coming from your backend, like here below. If I understood well your question

```
function store() {
                axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/transaction', transaction)
                .then(() => {
                    router.push({
                        name: 'transaction.index'
                    });
                }).catch((err) => {
                    validation.value = err.response.data.errors // added .errors
                    console.log(validation)
                });
            }
```